# How do you import a file in python with spaces in the name?

Tags: python, import, filenames, spaces

Do I *have to* take out all the spaces in the file name to import it, or is there some way of telling `import` that there are spaces?

Comment: Could you show some code please? Normally Python has no problem with spaces in filenames. (Oh wait, unless you're talking about the `import` statement, in which case Python doesn't support spaces in module names.)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should take the spaces out of the filename. Because the filename is used as the identifier for imported modules (i.e. `foo.py` will be imported as `foo`) and Python identifiers can't have spaces, this isn't supported by the `import` statement.

If you *really* need to do this for some reason, you can use the `__import__` function:

```
foo_bar = __import__("foo bar")
```

This will import `foo bar.py` as `foo_bar`. This behaves a little bit different than the `import` statement and you should avoid it.

Comment: And you can do something like this too (if you module name that begins with number for example): ```solution1 = __import__( "foo bar", fromlist="ClassOrMethodName")```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do something like `from foo_bar import *` (but with a space instead of an underscore), you can use execfile (docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile)):

```
execfile("foo bar.py")
```

though it's better practice to avoid spaces in source file names.

Comment: Just to add, in Python 3 it would be [`exec(open("foo bar.py", "r").read())`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=execfile#builtins)

Comment: This won't create a namespace for the module

Comment: `from foo_bar import *` likely doesn't behave the same as `execfile("foo_bar")` if foo_bar sets  `__all__ = [...]` (which controls what is exported when using from the *-import

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `importlib.import_module` function, which is a wrapper around `__import__`.

```
foo_bar_mod = importlib.import_module("foo bar")
```

or

```
foo_bar_mod = importlib.import_module("path.to.foo bar")
```

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

Comment: This is the correct approach in modern Python, assuming that it is correct to use the normal Python machinery to *find* the module.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Banks' answer, if you are importing another file that you haven't saved in one of the directories Python checks for importing directories, you need to add the directory to your path with

```
import sys
sys.path.append("absolute/filepath/of/parent/directory/of/foo/bar")
```

before calling

```
foo_bar = __import__("foo bar")
```

or

```
foo_bar = importlib.import_module("foo bar")
```

This is something you don't have to do if you were importing it with `import <module>`, where Python will check the current directory for the module. If you are importing a module from the same directory, for example, use

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
foo_bar = __import__('foo_bar')
```

Hope this saves someone else trying to import their own weirdly named file or a Python file they downloaded manually some time :)