# How do I import a module from within a Pycharm project?

Tags: python, pycharm

In my project, the file structure is as follows:

root/folder1/folder2/script1.py

root/folder1/folder2/script2.py

I have a statement in script2.py that says "import script1", and Pycharm says no module is found. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import as object :

`from root.folder1.folder2 import script1`

To import a function of your script:

`from root.folder1.folder2.script1 import NameOfTheFunction`

Comment: One more thing, how does this work if there's a space in the folder name?

Comment: You should remove them or use another way to import. Look at the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123517/how-do-you-import-a-file-in-python-with-spaces-in-the-name