# python: import module from different file directory, with folder names having spaces

Tags: python, import, module, spyder

I already know this will be  (wrongly, in my opinion) labelled as duplicate because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852140/whitespaces-in-the-path-of-windows-filepath) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123517/how-do-you-import-a-file-in-python-with-spaces-in-the-name), which I've already looked at.

However my problem is different, and cannot be solved with the answers found there.

So I have a python script in `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My folders\Projects\My stuff\Last Folder\some_file.py`. From this I want to import a file in the same directory, i.e. inside `Last Folder`, for this I just use `import file`.
However, then I have a file in `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Other Folder\My Other Projects\ My Other Stuff\other_file.py`. As you can see the folders have spaces.

Now in the second of the two links above we are told how to import a python file with spaces in the name, a python file, not a folder!

In the second link, the user wants to just open a file using os.

I instead want to import it. How do I do it? When I try

```
import Users.Me.Desktop.My Other Folder.My Other Projects.My Other Stuff.other_file.py
```

it says "invalid syntax"  because of the spaces. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123517/how-do-you-import-a-file-in-python-with-spaces-in-the-name will help you. Please go through it

Comment: @priyaraj I am not having problems with spaces in the file name

Comment: Have you tried something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: @SuperShoot I better not do things like that because I have files with the same names, and I am not the only one using Spyder on this computer

Comment: Did you see this answer which doesn't permanently add to path variable if that is a concern to you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702243/6560549

Comment: path = r"C:\c:\<foldername>\<folder name with space>....\welcome.py"
import path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\Users\Me\Desktop\My folders\Projects\My stuff\Last Folder\some_file.py.') 
# From this I want to import a file in the same directory, i.e. inside Last Folder, for this I just use import file. However, then I have a file in C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Other Folder\My Other Projects\ My Other Stuff
from other_file import *
```

Comment: * means import all functions

Answer (score 0):

I needed to import a `utils.py` file into a Google Colab Notebook and this worked for me, combining the solution from Surya and [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q#scrollTo=c99EvWo1s9-x).

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import sys
sys.path.append("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks")  # note the absolute path
print(sys.path)

from utils import a, b, c
```