# Importing a specific function from a file with a space in its name

Tags: python, import, whitespace, python-import

I am trying to import just one function from a .py file which has a space in its title. Due to external constraints, I cannot rename the file.

My first try was:

```
from File 1 import my_func
```

But that got a SyntaxError. Following advice on other StackOverflow, I found ways to import all the functions from a module/file:

V1:

```
exec(open("File 1.py").read())
```

V2:

```
globals().update(vars(__import__('File 1')))
```

However, I would like to only import my_func. I would also prefer to do this without using other modules like importlib. Any help is very much appreciated, I am still learning!

Comment: **Even without** the "space in the filename" problem, Python's import system **only ever** imports complete modules, and then optionally rebinds the names of things that were defined in that module. There is no way to "only import my_func" because **all of the top-level code must run before** we can know for sure that there even is a `my_func` to import, or what or where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the answer as requsted:
Source: [How do you import a file in python with spaces in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9123517/5545546).

Importing single function from a module with spaces in name without using importlib is simply impossible, since your only weapon here is `__import__`.

Your only option is to import the whole module and only keep functions you like. But it still imports **the whole module**.

#### Important notice

Getting rid of spaces and other non-alphanumeric symbols from module names is strongly recommended.

#### Example

File 1.py

```
def foo():
    print("Foonction.")

def spam():
    print("Get out!")
```

main.py

```
globals()["foo"] = getattr(__import__("File 1"),"foo")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a simplified example of the real scenario. (It's not actually called File 1!). I read the link provided, but it did not answer the original question, so please could I have some more assistance?

Comment: @JimmyCarlos Despite the real name of the module might be sensible, it is not sensible to keep non-alphanumeric characters in the file name. You should never be constrained externally to do things the wrong way. Try changing the policies to camel case or underscores. *ModuleName* or *module_name* are the only **right** approaches here.