# Importing a package with a keyword in path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a package in which one of the namespaces is the keyword 'import'. How is it best to do this? Would the folder need to be renamed?

Example:

```
import protobuf.import.import_enum_pb2 as importEnum
```

This gives an invalid syntax error.

I have started to look at using `__ import __` function instead-but wondered if there is a better workaround I haven't found a quotation or escaping method that works.

Comment: Did you name that package, or is it outside your control? Because that's absolutely terrible and should not be done. Like ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo_bar = __import__("foo bar")
```

Also see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123517/how-do-you-import-a-file-in-python-with-spaces-in-the-name#:~:text=4%20Answers&text=You%20should%20take%20the%20spaces,supported%20by%20the%20import%20statement.&text=This%20will%20import%20foo%20bar.py%20as%20foo_bar%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123517/how-do-you-import-a-file-in-python-with-spaces-in-the-name#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=You%20should%20take%20the%20spaces,supported%20by%20the%20import%20statement.&text=This%20will%20import%20foo%20bar.py%20as%20foo_bar%20).

Comment: Thank you, the problem with that is it will only take the first namespace so when nested it from the example that would just return "protobuf"

Comment: Ah I think you're trying to do a 'relative' import. I don't have prior experience with this subject but this is what I found: 

If I interpret this correctly, you should do as follows:
`import protobuf`
`import "import.protobuf.import_enum_pb2"`

# a.proto
package foo;
import "b.proto";
import "sub/c.proto";
import "sub/sub/d.proto";

Have you tried the documentation on this? Maybe this makes more sense to you than me? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing_definitions

Comment: Please read [answer]. If the question is best answered by citing an answer on another question and giving a one-line code example, then it is a duplicate, and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

Have found this can be done using `importlib`

Example:

```
errorseverity = importlib.import_module(' protobuf.import.import_enum_pb2')
```

`importlib` see documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module