# Python import module with spaces in directories and directory levels up

Tags: python, import, lib, relative-import

I'm 'reposting' this question with more detail because I feel it was misunderstood the first time. I have a folder structure that looks like so:

```
folder w space
       ├── folder1
       │      └── subfolder1
       │              └── file_1.py
       └── folder2
              └── folder w space2
                       └── file_2.py
                       └── __init__.py
```

I'm needing to have  `file_1.py` import the methods from `file_2.py`. Notice that `file_2.py`, in relation to `file_1.py`, is 3 directories up and then 3 directories down. I would, in theory, write the relative import as so:

```
from ...folder2 import folder w space2.file2
```

However this is not valid due to the spacing in the subfolder. An absolute import is even worse because the base folder contains spaces too:

```
from folder w space.folder2.folder w space2.file2
```

With this, how can I access the contents of `file_2.py` without:

1. Renaming the folders (I don't own them so I can't even if I wanted to)
2. Without using `sys.path.append()` (does not work well in our production env)
3. Moving `file_2.py` (for organization must stay where it is)

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852140/whitespaces-in-the-path-of-windows-filepath

Answer (score 0):

You can use [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

```py
# bar.py
import importlib
importlib.import_module("folder with spaces.foo")     

# folder with spaces/foo.py
print('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `__import__()` allows to support spaces in import statements:

```
sample_with_spaces = __import__("sample with spaces.foo")

sample_with_spaces.foo.hello()
```

Found it in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123555/6180150

> filename is used as the identifier for imported modules (i.e. foo.py will be imported as foo) and Python identifiers can't have spaces, this isn't supported by the import statement

So instead of letting the import statement set the identifier, you do that manually by assigning `__import__("sample with spaces.foo")` to the identifier you select yourself. In my example it is the identifier `sample_with_spaces`.

EDIT:

I think in your case when executing the script within a subfolder, it's the easiest way to update the working dir like below.

```
import os

os.chdir("..") # move up as much as needed
sample_with_spaces = __import__("sample with spaces.foo")

sample_with_spaces.foo.hello()
```

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) says, this method is discouraged in favour of using `importlib.import_module()`

Comment: I think this only works for imports that are relative to the cwd, I think `__import__` wouldn't work for going up directories as I'd need it to

Comment: I think it would work. But important is, from where you run your python file. Are you running it from the child folder or from the root folder? Depending on that you would have to set your imports and for simplicity root is then always the best option.

Comment: @schilli yes I should have clarified that, I'm running main from 'subfolder1' in my diagram. I actually don't own that file either meaning I can't move it. I think that's my primary issue. Any suggestions or how to use `__import__` for this case?

Comment: @mmarion I see. It sounds like a really tough setting. I updated my question with my best idea for importing from a parent dir by changing the working dir. Like AdamMcKay said the python docs suggest to use importlib instead of `__import__`, but I didn't adapt my code in that direction, so it'll be best if you follow that advise, too.

Comment: And you can do something like this too (if you module name that begins with number for example): ```solution = __import__( "foo bar", fromlist="ClassOrMethodName")```