# Python import module from a file very far from main()

Tags: python, import, absolute-path, relative-import

I have a folder structure of Python files that looks like so:

```
folder w space
       ├── folder1
       │      └── subfolder1
       │              └── file_1.py *is main*
       └── folder2
              └── folder w space2
                       └── file_2.py
                       └── __init__.py
```

I'm needing to have `file_1.py` (file that has main) import `file_2.py` as a package. Notice that `file_2.py`, in relation to `file_1.py`, is 3 directories up and then 3 directories down. I would, in theory, write the relative import as so:

```
from ...folder2 import folder w space2.file2
```

However this is not valid due to the spacing in the subfolder. An absolute import is even worse because the base folder contains spaces too:

```
import folder w space.folder2.folder w space2.file2
```

With this, how can I import `file_2.py` as a module without:

1. Renaming the folders (I don't own them so I can't even if I wanted to)
2. Without using `sys.path.append()` (does not work in our production env)
3. Moving `file_2.py` (for organization must stay where it is)
4. Hopefully not install any further libraries (isn't absolutely necessary but it would be a whole process for me to add new libraries to our production env)

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: I think you're going to need to either modify `sys.path`, which you don't want to do, or use an environment variable (which requires external setup).  Personally, I prefer to prepend my own directories to the fromt of `sys.path` rather than appending them to the end.

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I just call main in file_1.py

Comment: Can you give me the command line?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `py file_1.py`. I'm just calling the file raw

Comment: "Very far from main" has **nothing to do with** the problem identified.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you could [rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123555/281545) the imports to be able to run this with spaces in the folder names your relative/absolute imports would blow for other reasons. Remove the spaces from the folder names (make so they are valid python identifiers) and then run your main as:

```
$ cd "folder w space"
$ py -m folder1.subfolder1.file_1
```

This will make python see the folders as packages (cause its scans the current working dir) and is the recommended way of running a python script. Your imports will work out of the box:

```
from ...folder2 import folder_w_space2.file2 # or
import folder2.folder_w_space2.file2
```